# Flag similar cell values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, similarity

I have created a pandas dataframe called `df` with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'Feature': ["Sales Acct.", "Director", "Sales Acc.","Manager","Direct.", "Miner"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
print(df)

       Feature
0  Sales Acct.
1     Director
2   Sales Acc.
3      Manager
4      Direct.
5        Miner
```

I need to create a new variable (called "category") which flags the "similar" cells.
I was thinking about Python's SequenceMatcher. For example:

```
from  difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

x = 'Sales Acct.'
y = "Sales Acc."

z = similar(x,y)
print(z)
```

In this example, the similarity ratio is about 0.95.

So, my question is: is there a pythonic way to add a variable to the above dataframe that identifies the "similar" (e.g. : similarity ratio > 0.50) cells?

Ideally, the resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
       Feature  Category
0  Sales Acct.         1
1     Director         2
2   Sales Acc.         1
3      Manager         3
4      Direct.         2
5        Miner         4
```

Comment: By the way there could be a logical problem if you have e. g. "aabb" being similar enough to "bb" which in turn is similar enough to "bbcc" which isn't similar enough to the first "aabb". How to set the categories here?

Comment: I see no way to speed this up with pandas so the Pythonic way would be an outer for-loop over the rows and an inner for-loop over the rows below the current row and and compare the rows. Instead of this you can also use something from "itertools" and a single loop to make it look fancier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with the dataframe and the function you provided:

```py
# Calculate ratios
df = df.assign(
    Match=df["Feature"].map(
        lambda x: max(
            [similar(x, value) for value in df["Feature"]],
            key=lambda x: x if x != 1 else 0,
        )
    )
).sort_values(by="Match", ascending=False)

# Add same category number (1, 2,...) only if ratio >= 0.8
df["Category"] = (
    df["Match"]
    .round(6)
    .map(
        {
            key: i + 1 if key >= 0.8 else pd.NA
            for i, key in enumerate(df["Match"].unique().round(6))
        }
    )
)

# Add a different category number (3, 4, ...) for rows with ratio < 0.8
df.loc[df["Category"].isna(), "Category"] = [
    df["Category"].max() + i for i in range(1, len(df[df["Category"].isna()]) + 1)
]

# Cleanup
df = df.sort_index().drop(columns="Match")
```

And so:

```py
print(df)
# Output
       Feature Category
0  Sales Acct.        1
1     Director        2
2   Sales Acc.        1
3      Manager        3
4      Direct.        2
5        Miner        4
```